# jQuery Mobile Beta 2 - option tag selection issue (visual)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

The option tag used to change colour when selected, (great way of letting users know its selected).
By default, the background would turn blue with white text and a gradient bullet on the left matching the background blue only slightly darker. ( Nice >_< )

Now with beta 2, the background color doesn't activate, although the bullet on the left is turning blue.
The result is a little weird, and no longer obvious for users.

Can anyone think of a fix in the meantime?
I've looked through some CSS without much luck so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! found it.
Updated CSS in beta2 causing the radio button to look un-selected on selection.
According to the jQuery mobile blog it is less overpowering, but I think it lets it down in usability!
Added the following CSS to my beta2 CSS file and it rolled back gracefully...
--Note the update for checkbox also.--

.ui-radio-on, label.ui-checkbox-on {
    border:1px solid #155678;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background:#4596ce;
    text-shadow:0 -1px 1px #145072;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-    stop(0,#85bae4),color-stop(1,#5393c5));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#85bae4,#5393c5);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#85bae4,#5393c5);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#85bae4,#5393c5);
    background-image:linear-gradient(top,#85bae4,#5393c5);
}

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're talking about [checkboxes](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/forms/checkboxes/index.html), you'll need to add this to your stylesheet.

```
label.ui-checkbox-on
{
  border: 1px solid #155678;
  color: White;
  background: #4596CE;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #145072;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope not checkboxes, to clarify I mean radio inputs: <input type="radio" />